# Flyway to update two databases

Tags: flyway, micronaut

I have micrnaut based java application. which uses two databases, i have set up the two datasources

but how can i use flyway to load different data into the two databases

directory is as follows, which works for single db as following examples:

resources -> db->migration -> V1__data.sql

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have two datasources as below:

```yaml
datasources:
  default: 
    url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:flywayDb1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'
    username: 'sa'
    password: ''
    driverClassName: 'org.h2.Driver'
  other: 
    url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:flywayDb2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'
    username: 'sa'
    password: ''
    driverClassName: 'org.h2.Driver'
```

You can configure Flyway as below:

```yaml
flyway:
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
      locations:
        - classpath:db/migrations/default
    other:
      enabled: true
      locations:
        - classpath:db/migrations/other
```

Check the [micronaut Flyway manual](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-flyway/latest/guide/) for more information.